# Modify String to Quote Attribute Values in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

```
Username=bob sirname=the     position=buil=der
```

I want to convert it to:

```
Username="bob" sirname="the" position="build=der"
```

But problem is in *part of position* cause there is also `=` character in value of it. Also after adding quotes, I want to delete all `=` inside the "".

Comment: Please show what you already tried and avoid questions just begging for code.

Comment: I have done it using so many str_replace like :    str_replace('e=','e="',$str).  So it ll convert username= to username=".   But it was so complicated thts why i asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$str = 'Username=bob sirname=the position=buil=der';

//slice your string into parts (separated by spaces) and loop through them
$parts = explode(' ', $str);

foreach ($parts as &$part)
{
    //slice every part to pieces (separated by '=' character)
    $pieces = explode('=', $part);

    //the first piece is the name of your pair
    $name = array_shift($pieces);
    //all the other pieces are joined to make a value of your pair
    $value = implode('', $pieces);
    //you want your pair to look like this: name="value"
    $part = $name . '="' . $value . '"';
}

//join the pairs back to a string, separate them by spaces
$str = implode(' ', $parts);

//output the final string
echo $str;
```

I get:

Username="bob" sirname="the" position="builder"

I believe that's what you need.